# Call settings missing in settings after updating to Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, settings, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I updated my Google Nexus S to Android 4.0.3. Now the call settings seems to be missing and video calling is not working. When I hard boot the device it shows "LOCK STATE -LOCKED".

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm responding late, I too faced this problem today and could figure the call setting by following procedure below:

---

1. Press the Phone symbol from the Home screen
2. Settings button & select 'Settings'.
3. Under Other Call Settings select 'Additional Settings'
4. Caller ID

Is that what you're looking for? HTH